# R flextable How to open a hyperlink in new browser tab

Tags: r, flextable

I am creating an R `flextable` with one column containing hyperlinks. To this task I am using the hyperlink_text function and the as_paragraph function.

```
myfl <- myfl %>% compose( j = "file_path",
         value = as_paragraph( hyperlink_text(x = "enrichment result",
                                              url = file_path ) ) )
```

Klicking the link in the rendered html document opens it in the same window.
What can I do so that the link opens a new browser tab?